# The 7 Essential Meta Questions

Tags: discussion, essential-questions

As we are coming half way the private beta we should start discussing and preparing some things for the general public to come in. This question is mainly meant to show how far we are with "[The 7 Essential Meta Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)" and to have a nice browsing point.

1. Are questions about [subject] on or off topic?

   - [R](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-to-answer-r-questions) and [Programming](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35/how-much-programming-here) questions
   - [Visualization](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109/what-to-do-with-pure-visualization-questions) questions
   - [Machine Learning](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/is-machine-learning-a-part-of-statistical-analysis) and [Speech Recognition](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-much-can-we-ask-about-speech-recognition) questions
2. What should our FAQ contain?

   - [FAQ thread](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-should-our-faq-contain)
3. How should we tag questions about {subject}?

   - [Tag rename requests](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120/tag-rename-suggestions)
4. What should our domain name be?

   - [Site Name / Domain name](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21/what-should-our-site-be-called-what-should-our-domain-name-be)
5. What should our logo and site design look like?

   - No topics yet
6. Who should the moderators be?

   - [Who should the moderators be?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133/who-should-the-moderators-be)
7. How do we promote our site?

   - [Posters](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126/ideas-and-designs-for-posters)
   - [Email Blurb](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142/email-blurb-for-public-beta)

Let's give together input on all of these topics as it is important to but a strong basis now for how the site will look like. Obviously some points (like 5. and 7.) are not so relevant yet, but let's at least start discussing about the five others.

(Community wiki, so feel free to update this question as new topics are made)

Comment: Great job organizing these threads.