# Tag rename suggestions

Tags: discussion, tags

Which tags do you think should be renamed? Let's add here tag-rename requests as answers. We can vote up answers to indicate that we agree with that tag-rename request and use the comments to discuss the request.

Unless there is a discussion about a tag-rename, anyone can go ahead to change the tags after some time and upvotes. This to prevent that somebody just retags everything when a request comes, now matter what the others think... When we get moderators this task will shift to them.

**Please all take a look now (and vote) and suggest more tag renames if you have.**

Comment: Don't you mean adding tag-rename requests as 'answers'? I edited your question to reflect this. Feel free to rollback if that is not what you meant.

Comment: I don't know how other meta's do it, but it seems that waiting for 4 upvotes takes a very long time. Should we just wait a day for negative comments and than go ahead with a rename? Or lower the number of votes?

Comment: Perhaps, we should have something like: "We will implement a re-tag request unless we get -4 negative votes within 5 days of posting." or some such.

Comment: The dynamics seem to work well so I kind of removed/relaxed any requirements... As long as people wait a while

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Current tag synonym candidates](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/current-tag-synonym-candidates)

Answer (score 5):

**Tag Synonym Created**

[fundamentals] (x6) -> [introductory] (x2) or [beginner]

Note: [beginner] is one of the most popular tags on SO, so not sure if it would be helpful to have some consistency across sites.

**DONE**

Comment: You have my strong support for beginner.

Comment: I also vote for beginner

Comment: I forgot to mark this, but I did this one already before http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172/i-just-want-to-take-this-on-early-can-we-please-please-not-use-the-beginner-t was posted

Answer (score 4):

**Tag Synonym created**

[financial] (x1) -> [finance] (x2)

**DONE**

Answer (score 4):

Another one that has turned up a few times is "Resources for learning *x*" (example [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/328/resources-for-learning-about-the-statistical-analysis-of-financial-data/) and [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138/resources-for-learning-r/)).  Maybe also tag these as "beginner"?

**DONE**

Comment: And of 2. I would drop the tutorials tag or add also books. I favor dropping tutorials

Answer (score 3):

**Tag Synonym Created**

[random-variables] -> [random-variable]

**DONE**

Comment: Or the opposite.  There is also [random-variate].  And I'm not sure what to make of just [random].

Comment: I think the one [random] tag existing should be [randomness]

Comment: Any objections against changing this tag before the start of the public beta tonight? If we decide later on plural than we can retag them easily, but until then there is no inconsistency.

Comment: @Peter Go do it.

Answer (score 3):

**Tag Synonym created**

[model-choice] -> [model-selection]

**DONE**

Answer (score 3):

**TAG SYNONYM Created**

[modelling] (x3) == [modeling] (x9)

**RENAME DONE**

Comment: See also http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36/modeling-vs-modelling-tag . I am in favor of taking indeed the one with one l, as that one naturally occurred. Should be synonyms imho

Comment: I agree, if there's a programmatic option to make them equivalent that would be best.

Comment: Also, I totally missed that previous question - thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Dangling [image] and [processing] in [image-processing].
**DONE**

Answer (score 2):

**Tag Synonym created**

Not sure what to do with this, but a number of questions cover either "[layman](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layman)" or "[plain english](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22/bayesian-and-frequentist-reasoning-in-plain-english)".  Should we just make these all into "introductory" or "beginner"?

**DONE** (beginner is chosen)

Answer (score 2):

**Tag Synonym Created**

[fa] -> [factor-analysis]? This is much less common than PCA.

**DONE**

Answer (score 2):

**Tag synonym created**

```
distribution[*2] -> distributions[*23]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Tag Synonym Created**

[homogeneity-of-variance] (x1) -> [homogeneity] (x1)

**DONE**

Answer (score 1):

**Tag Synonym Created**

[pca] (x2) -> [principal-components] (x1)
**DONE THE OPPOSITE**

Comment: I think that I maybe like the pca tag more. Any reason for preferring the long-but-not-complete version? Or should both exist, where pca are questions really the method and principal-components for other questions where the principal components play a role?

Comment: I just thought "principal-components" was more descriptive, but I don't have a strong feeling on this. Go with pca if you prefer. I don't think we need both.

Comment: I'm not sure either. For example we also have the tag fa for factor analyses. That one I personally didn't catch the abbreviation immediately

Comment: I vote for pca, because it is more familiar than the full name.

Comment: I vote for pca as well.

Comment: I assumed we have consensus.

Answer (score -2):

**Tag Synonyms create**

> book -> books
>
> textbooks -> books
>
> textbook -> books

Is this change OK?

---

[books] == [textbooks]

**PROPOSED RESOLUTION**: Make a synonym of books and textbooks, with books being the standard displayed value. *DIAMOND NEEDED*

Comment: Any objections against changing this tag before the start of the public beta tonight?

Comment: Just check that they really are textbooks and not some other genre of book. Otherwise, please go ahead.

Comment: @Rob what do you think how this question should be tagged? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/363/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-statistician-should-read

Comment: @Peter. I'd leave that as "books". Lady Tasting Tea is certainly not a textbook. Nor is Fooled by Randomness.

Comment: @Rob Shall we at least make them both plural or singular? I think I prefer plural in this case for both tags

Comment: `textbook` should be a synonym for default tag `books`

Comment: @SilentGhost So you suggest dropping textbook completely and using only books?

Comment: @Peter I agree with them being plural

Comment: I changed for now all `textbook` to plural. Anyone else an opinion on making everything `books`? I think it might make sense.

Comment: @Peter: tag synonyms. I suggest that `books` and `textbooks` will be made synonyms. With `books` being the default view.

Comment: Ok, I'm unfamiliar with that option, but it sounds good to me. I guess only mods can put that on?