# Who should the moderators be? [LOCKED]

Tags: discussion, essential-questions, moderation

Based on [the web-apps template](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57986/how-to-organize-a-formal-moderator-election-on-a-beta-se-site), we should be choosing candidates to be our site moderators.

- Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user's profile so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about their self. This can be just practical stuff like which hours and how many hours they expect to spend on the site, but also some motivation.
- From the top voted nominees a number of temporary moderators will be appointed, until the site is out of beta and real elections can be held.

Some guidelines:

1. Must be a currently registered user in good standing
2. Must have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
3. Should exhibit patience and fairness at all times in their questions, answers, and comments.
4. Should lead by example, showing respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
5. They should want the responsibility. Nominating users isn’t the same as an obligation. It’s purely voluntary!

When nominating, please put the name of the nominee as a heading (with a #) and as a link to their real profile. Also add a link to their meta profile. (See the already provided answers). After that, please keep them empty for the nominees to add information themselves.

Besides voting, everybody could off course also point out in the comments why that nominee is a good candidate to be moderator or not.

Temporary moderators have been appointed by the StackExchange team so the site can function smoothly until moderators are elected. The temporary moderators are [mbq](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/88/mbq), [csgillespie](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/8/csgillespie), [Shane](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/5/shane) and [Rob Hyndman](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/159/rob-hyndman).

Read more about [the moderator nomination process here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57986/how-to-organize-a-formal-moderator-election-on-a-beta-se-site).

Comment: I have no idea what I'm doing, so please feel free to edit away...

Comment: My main concern is that we may end up voting for each other. I am not sure how comfortable I would be with being a moderator with such scant voting numbers. Do we have enough users from the main site visiting the meta? Just a thought.

Comment: This will be open until a week or so after the public beta.  So it's not like we're deciding today.  There should be plenty of votes by the end.

Comment: @Shane: That makes sense.

Comment: Hmm... my gut instinct was "DIRK!" but he's not even a user of the site.  Does anybody know if he plans to be?  Because frankly, regardless of his participation in the beta, his SO record shows him to be moderator material for sure (if he wants it).

Comment: I've locked this thread as the appointment of temporary moderators has been finalized. There will be a new election process for the moderators in the longer-term.

Answer (score 15):

## [Rob Hyndman](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/159/rob-hyndman)

I'd be happy to help out as a moderator. Most days I can be checking the site regularly throughout the day. My time zone is UTC+10 which is nicely complementary to most other people.

[meta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/users/159/rob-hyndman)

Comment: +1 for Rob. Very knowledgeable (is a professor) and has fair and balanced answers. Proposing this site has shown he has interest for the community.

Comment: He's also in Australia and can cover that time zone.

Comment: +1 for Rob, As Peter Said... Professor, Editorin chief of a rank A journal, tones of publications... is moderation time consuming ?

Comment: If I find it too time-consuming, I could step down after 6-12 months, but I'd really like to see the site well-established and functioning smoothly first.

Answer (score 12):

## [Shane](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/5/shane)

[meta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5/shane)

Comment: Besides the good answers and the active involvement in the meta site, Shane also has impressive StackOverflow record. This shows that he is prepared and willing to spend a lot of time in helping users out.

Comment: Now officially the first who broke the 1k rep.

Comment: Just saw that when I was checking to see how many users could retag questions.  Unbelievable.

Answer (score 9):

## [mbq](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/88/mbq)

[meta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/users/88/mbq)

Thanks for nomination; I believe I can take it. I live in a CET zone (UTC+1/2). I have a nice academic job, so generally I have a lot of time (except for out of a sudden emerging deadlines).

Comment: mbq has also been extremely helpful and active on both the main site and meta (answering more questions than anyone else so far).

Answer (score 6):

## [Srikant Vadali](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/28/srikant-vadali)

[meta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28/srikant-vadali)

I am in the Eastern Time Zone (United States). I can visit the site throughout the day until the start of the Fall semester (Sep '10) when I teach on MWF. On these days my visits will be sporadic and restricted to after 9 pm EST. On TR I am a bit more flexible.

Feel free to ask any questions (via the comments to this 'answer') if you feel you need additional information.

Comment: @Srikant Could you maybe put in your profile some info like your job / study place?

Comment: @Peter I added some basic info.

Comment: Great, thanks! That gives some good information!

Answer (score 6):

## [Colin Gillespie](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/8/colin-gillespie)

[meta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8/colin-gillespie)

I'd be happy to help out as a moderator.

Currently, I'm a statistics lecturer at Newcastle University, UK and so my time zone is BST.

Ps I'm away from the office this week which is why I've been slow to respond and not answer any questions in the main site. I won't be fully back until Monday 2nd August.

Comment: Colin has actively contributed to the community, is a lecturer in the field, and lives in the UK (so he could cover that time zone).

Comment: @Colin: That's good...thought that you might have disappeared!

Comment: Let's just say that hotels lie about wireless access!

Comment: @Colin: I'm about to take off for a week myself, and I'm pretty sure that wireless won't be an option...

Answer (score 6):

## [Dirk Eddelbuettel](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/334/dirk-eddelbuettel)

[meta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/users/334/dirk-eddelbuettel)

Comment: Is this nomination base on his StackOverflow record?

Comment: Yes, and his monstrous contributions to the R-project.  http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/  And his no-nonsense answers (e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/775/operations-research-v-s-statistical-analysis).

Comment: @Shane Yes, he has done an impressive amount of nice stuff! Good to have you here Dirk! Still, putting e.g. for the only answer posted is a bit... funny ;) But yes, if Dirk wants to be really involved in this community he is a good moderator candidate

Comment: I wouldn't shy away from putting forward other "known people" as candidates here, although clearly contribution on the site is an important criteria.  Any others?

Comment: @Shane I noticed rcs...

Comment: @Shane And hadley.

Answer (score 3):

## [Graham Cookson](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/215/graham-cookson)

[meta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/users/215/graham-cookson)

Comment: I've been impressed with Graham's answers on the main site, although he hasn't used meta at all yet.  He also lives in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>[Peter Smit](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/190/peter-smit), [meta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/users/190/peter-smit)</strike>

I hereby decline my nomination. Besides the fact that there are much better and knowledgeable candidates, I am afraid that moderation would be so fun that it would take all my time and prevent me from ever finishing my thesis :)

Comment: Peter has been really active in shaping the community on meta, has had very thoughtful ideas, and superb answers on the main site.