# Shall we advertise votings in the system message?

Tags: discussion, moderation, site-name

I think we should reflect there (this blue bar with "got a question about the site...") the ongoing moderator and site name elections; both topics are dying with embarrassingly small number of votes, so maybe this will bring the community attention?

Edit: So I think the idea has some support; now what do you think about the text itself?
Rob is probably better in this kind of things, I would write:

Hot topics on [meta](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com): [Moderator election](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133/who-should-the-moderators-be), [voting on the site name](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21/what-should-our-site-be-called-what-should-our-domain-name-be), [extending scope](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252/should-we-allow-more-computing-questions).

Edit2: Ok, the system message now changed. If you think it can be somewhat corrected or changed, suggest as an answer.

Comment: I've made a small edit to the name question to bring it back to the top of the list.

Comment: By the way as moderators do you have access to any tools that will tell us how many users are 'consistently' using the site? Define consistency as visit at least every other day perhaps?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm still figuring out what tools we actually have.

Comment: I would be inclined to advertise this question first: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/252/should-we-allow-more-computing-questions It is a big change to the site that all users should be informed of.

Comment: @csgillespie Don't bother to extend the proposition in my post.

Comment: @mbq: Sorry I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @csgillespie I meant that you could just change my post and add this thread the the project of new system message.

Comment: +1 I support this idea.  Getting more attention for those threads would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

But, we do not have an ongoing moderator election, do we? Yes, advertising the site name elections and in general motivating people to come to the meta is a good idea.

Comment: We are temporary moderators, and we will be replaced by people selected by this voting.

Comment: I know that but I was under the impression that a new election thread will be started a few weeks later. I felt that the existing election thread was only for the temporary positions.

Comment: I see no problem in continuing this one, still I will ask about it .