# Email Blurb for Public Beta

Tags: discussion

Some of us will have the ability to announce the existence of this site via email listservs. Can we come up with an email blurb that we can use?

I will write a sample email blurb as an answer. Feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have statistics related questions that you would like answers to? Do you often feel that you would be able to work more productively if you had access to a site which has high quality questions and answers on various statistics related topics?

If your answer is yes to the above two questions then click on: http://stats.stackexchange.com.

This website is built on the very successful model of Questions & Answers pioneered by [Stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com). Please take a few minutes of your time to visit the site so that you can see for yourself how the site works. Please also read our [faq](https://stats.stackexchange.com/faq) to know more about the site works.

Comment: It may also be worth explicitly inviting those who don't necessarily have questions but can provide good answers.  I'm not sure how best to word that, though, so I'll leave it to someone else to add.