# Can we have the option of making a question CW but let the answers be non-CW?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, polystats-project

This feature is needed on Polystats projects that we are starting on [stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). See these threads for what they are: [What should be our first Polystats project?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2512/what-should-be-our-first-polystats-project) and [How about starting a Polystats Project?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/419/how-about-starting-a-polystats-project).

By design, the questions related to Polystats projects are more about housekeeping to ensure that the project moves from one phase to the next. Thus, marking them as CW makes a lot of sense. However, we need to encourage users to provide good answers especially in the later phases of the project. Thus, awarding rep for answers makes sense.

In any case, irrespective of whether this feature is implemented or not, is there a workaround to achieve the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround is this: Post a question without marking it as CW but request users not to vote for the question but to vote up answers as appropriate. This is not a perfect solution because of two issues:

1. Some users may still vote for the question and
2. More importantly, if the question is not voted up its prominence will go down over time.

A solution to issue 2 would be to make dummy edits at some reasonable frequency (perhaps once in 2 days for a week's duration) to ensure that at periodic intervals the question comes to the front page.

Comment: Currently implementing this workaround.

Answer (score 1):

No, at least in this version of SE engine. But you are free to post such a request to meta.stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, I had initially posted there but given that this request is specific to polystats I thought it may be better to post it here with a feature--request tag. I deleted my post from meta.stackoverflow before posting it here.

Comment: @Srikant Bad idea; SE team is not visiting this meta too often.

Comment: Let us wait for a few days. I was under the impression that anything tagged bug / feature-request gets their attention automatically (i.e., they do not have to visit meta as such to get notification of such requests). Is that not true?

Answer (score -1):

The other thing -- I am against leaving those questions non-CW. Reputation is not the only award for a good answer, there are also badges.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your answer. Don't you mean that you are against leaving polystats questions as CW?

Comment: As I wrote, I just think they should be CW.

Comment: Ok. I see your point but I feel that badges are not a sufficient motivator as they are not as prominent as rep. What is the downside of having rep for answers?

Comment: Downvoting hurts, so people are less willing to downvote bad ideas, answers in discussion-like threads are generating more reputation than in regular questions, what is a bit unfair, finally in CW people are free to edit other posts, so answers may evolve.

Comment: Yes downvoting hurts but you also need to encourage well thought out answers. I suppose that instead of downvoting a proposal that they do not like maybe people can upvote a proposal they do like. They also have the option of not voting but commenting on a answer to indicate which aspect they do not like. I suggest that we continue with the way it right now and change the system as needed for future iterations of these projects. Does that sound reasonable?