# Incoming... Machine Learning Questions

Tags: discussion, questions

There has been [strong support](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/492/are-the-machine-learning-questions-on-topic) to officially [merge Machine Learning with Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/should-machine-learning-se-be-merged-with-crossvalidated). Later this week, we will be migrating questions from the Machine Learning and making it an official part of this site.

I re-posted [**the Machine Learning announcement**](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1062/246) as an **answer** below, for your reference.

Be prepared to integrate these questions and this subject into your site. You can close questions that are blatantly off topic, but be mindful — this is a growing scope of questions looking for a best fit. We want to make every effort to accommodate the community on this site, and err towards being open-minded and make adjustments to accommodate the subject.

Comment: **To all**: Most of these questions likely will not need any action from our community.  Consider using the list provided by Rebecca as a guide to a collection of threads you might wish to read in the near future; I hope you enjoy them.  As you catch up, your help would be **much** appreciated in identifying any (near) duplicates, as well as any that might possibly be off topic.  When you run across such a situation, please just click on the `flag` link beneath the question to let a moderator know about it.  Thank you!

Comment: Now all we need is AI to be included and everybody can be very happy

Comment: Tried to go through and edit the tags on my own questions but quickly got: > **Too many edits** > You have already edited 5 of your own posts today (not including very recent posts). Further edits are not allowed until tomorrow. > Please contact a moderator if you require assistance.

Comment: @IvoFlipse and change the name of it to ML.SE ..... ;-)

Comment: Yeah, the system thinks you are self-vandalizing -- unfortunately I can't remove the blockade manually. We (mods) are working to fix untagged questions -- lack of machine-learning tag is not a big problem because many of the CV's original ML questions were missing this tag.

Comment: @mbq not just machine-learning tag - any tags that were used on ML.SE but didn't exist on stats.SE got lost on the way over, so some Q's have no tags at all

Comment: Precisely -- you can check that there are no more untagged posts from ML, we are working to adjust the rest.

Comment: Ok gone through them all.

Answer (score 11):

*This is a re-post of the Machine Learning announcement (since it is still in private beta):*

---

### The Future of Machine Learning as a Stack Exchange Subject

The "Machine Learning" Stack Exchange started with a proposal in Area 51. A groups of experts propose a subject they felt were *not* found on the Stack Exchange Network. In the meantime, you have a Stats SE ("Cross Validated") who [claim that "Machine Learning" is explicitly on topic](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/492/are-the-machine-learning-questions-on-topic) for that site. Still, the supporters of the ML site wonders if all machine learning topics are a good fit for Cross Validated.

**So what to do?** We're not experts in this domain, so we let the proposal continue to see how it develops in actual practice. As it turns out, about 85-95% of the questions being asked are a perfect fit for Cross Validated. Even now, there is still widespread support to welcome the Machine Learning questions on their site.

[**Should Machine Learning SE be merged with CrossValidated?**](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/should-machine-learning-se-be-merged-with-crossvalidated)

So be it. Around mid week, **we are going to migrate the questions** from "Machine Learning" to the Cross Validated site. Some will be closed as off topic, but for the most part, they would love to see your Machine Language questions there. ***Make* Machine Learning a strong subject on the Cross Validated site** by asking your questions there.

For the smaller group of questions that do *not* fit on that site, support the [**Computer Science**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636?phase=commitment) proposal. Bring your questions to these sites and make your presence known in the tags you care about. There is no purpose in continuing a sub-site like this when the subject is well-covered elsewhere.

A larger, more comprehensive site is a win-win to everyone.

Comment: A must read: http://www.r-statistics.com/2010/07/statistical-analysis-qa-website-did-stackoverflow-just-lose-it-to-metaoptimize-and-is-it-good-or-bad/

Comment: Thank you for the link Dov.  I almost forgot I put it up there.  What do you take from that post?

Comment: @TalGalili. I think that I'm the one that need to say "thank you for this post"... :) though at that time, you thought that there is sort of "battle" between the sites. SE become more statistically oriented where MO become a machine learning oriented. Hence, I think that although those fields are sometime overlap and each community can learn from each other, I think that ML could benefit from a site for its own. Theoretically, I wish to see it here at SE – as the setup here is more convenient. (Until this will happen, I think that will be mostly at MO). - Excuse me for my Israeli accent :)

Answer (score 3):

For informational purposes, the list of questions that were migrated were:

- [Classification with tall fat data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23335)
- [Why is there an asymmetry between the training step and evaluation step?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23331)
- [Possible to get a better ANN by removing some connections?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23340)
- [Fast method for finding best metaparameters of SVM (that is faster than grid search)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23509)
- [Creating a maximum entropy Markov model from an existing multi-input maximum entropy classifier](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23507)
- [What is a good method for designing an HTM network in terms of depth and breadth?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23505)
- [Domain-agnostic feature engineering that retains semantic meaning?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23502)
- [Probabilistic (Bayesian) vs Optimisation (Frequentist) methods in Machine Learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23501)
- [What's the correct way to test the significance of classification results](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23497)
- [What is the proper naming scheme for dataset parts?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23493)
- [Why do naive Bayesian classifiers perform so well?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23490)
- [Applying machine learning for DDoS filtering](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23488)
- [On what tasks does neuroevolution outperform basic application of neural networks or genetic algorithms?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23486)
- [What are alternatives to VC-dimension for measuring the complexity of neural networks?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23484)
- [Are there algorithms for computing "running" linear or logistic regression parameters?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23481)
- [Why do we assume that the error is normally distributed?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23479)
- [How to decide on the correct number of clusters?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23472)
- [Does a sparse training set adversely affect an SVM?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23470)
- [Problem specific regularization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23468)
- [Probability and log probability in hidden Markov models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23465)
- [Are machine learning techniques "approximation algorithms"?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23463)
- [Is there a Project Euler-alike for machine learning?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23459)
- [Dealing with datasets with a variable number of features](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23456)
- [Are associative networks still pertinent for data mining applications?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23454)
- [What language to use for genetic programming](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23451)
- [How to create recommender system that integrates both collaborative filtering and content features?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23448)
- [Why does Natural Language Processing not fall under Machine Learning domain?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23445)
- [Modern neural networks that build their own topology](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23439)
- [How would you design a machine learning system to play Angry Birds?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23435)
- [Are MFCCs the optimal method of representing music to a retrieval system?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23433)
- [Fiducial Inference in Machine Learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23431)
- [At what n do n-grams become counterproductive?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23429)
- [Classification of observation symbols in a HMM?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23427)
- [Automatic feature selection for anomaly detection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23426)
- [Multilayer neural networks for multivariate temporal data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23423)
- [Is whitening always good?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23420)
- [Dynamic recommender systems](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23417)
- [Classifier success rate and confidence intervals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23415)
- [How can I help ensure testing data does not leak into training data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23411)
- [Decision trees and backward pruning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23409)
- [Difference between dynamic programming and temporal difference learning in reinforcement learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23407)
- [Subtree replacement vs subtree raising](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23406)
- [Automatic data cleansing](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23403)
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23402
- [Approaches when learning from huge datasets?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23399)
- [Kernel matrix normalisation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23397)
- [What is standing in the way of pulsed neural networks being used in applications?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23395)
- [CCA/KCCA for more than two views](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23393)
- [How does a Support Vector Machine (SVM) work?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23391)
- [In boosting, why are the learners "weak"?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23388)
- [What is a kernel and what sets it apart from other functions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23386)
- [Independence in classification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23384)
- [Best bandit algorithm?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23382)
- [What are probabilistic approaches to finding the right number of clusters?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23380)
- [What is the Drosophila of AI now?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23377)
- [Are experts harmful?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23375)
- [Beyond Fisher kernels](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23373)
- [Dealing with very large time-series datasets](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23371)
- [Classification of conversations based on content](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23369)
- [Where do I find large face datasets?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23367)
- [Probabilistic outputs from SVMs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23365)
- [Online clustering](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23363)
- [Viable distance metric for text articles](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23360)
- [Continuous Multistate Ada-boost method?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23358)
- [MRF MAP inference for non-submodular pairwise terms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23357)
- [How to perform Gaussian process regression when  function being approximated changes over time?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23355)
- [PCA, LDA, CCA, and PLS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23353)
- [Large performance variance when using back-propagation in neural networks for feature extraction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23352)
- [Average case analysis of learning algorithms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23351)
- [Dealing with mixed categorical data: e.g. Heritage Health Prize data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23348)
- [Number of states and symbols in multi class Hidden Markov Model classifier](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23347)

Comment: Seems like none of them got the tag [machine-learning]?