# Don't use possibly-offtopic tag

Tags: discussion

Currently 3 questions are tagged possibly-offtopic. Why is this done? The close votes will show what we think what is offtopic and the discussion will be done here.

The tags are used to give useful information about the question, not to add some meta-information to them. Anyway, who would decide which are qualified as such, because that is very subjective.

Suggestion: Remove all this tags. If you find something offtopic -> do a close-vote as offtopic and open an meta-question if it is not evident.

Comment: +1 I agree completely.

Comment: surely, introduction of `possibly-offtopic-tag` on meta is at least as bad!

Comment: @SilentGhost Ehm, yeah, that's true... I will remove it

Comment: @dfknexus Ehm, the on-topic tag is useful as it are the discussions about what things are on-topic on the main-site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

I keep forgetting about how nice linked posts are these days.  Given this- I agree that we should definitely keep the tag space free of clutter and collect links in the associated Meta questions.

---

<strike>They are flagged possibly-off-topic because we have not figured out where to draw the lines yet.  See the following two discussions:</strike>

- [How much programming here?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35/how-much-programming-here)
- [How to answer R questions](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-to-answer-r-questions)

The flags are very important as they allow us to keep tabs on these questions.  This is important for two reasons:

- It allows us to easily find these questions so that they may be used as evidence to support discussions like the ones above that will decide policy.
- Once policy has been decided, they allow us to easily find the questions and deal with them in a uniform fashion.

Please don't remove the flags until the relevant discussions have been completed and we have decided on guidelines.

Comment: I would suggest just collecting the links to the questions in the meta discussion. This allows for quick lookup, using as evidence and dealing with them afterwards. No need to clutter the tag-space with this.

Comment: @Peter I keep forgetting about the new support for linked posts, hasn't quite sunk into my brain yet.  After some consideration I think you are right on this point.

Comment: Nice that you agree. I think only that you are now quite hasty with removing all the tags. Maybe we should wait a few hours/ a day to hear everyones opinion...