# Why are some questions locked by the Community user?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, migration, deleted-questions

This is in a way a followup on [We have a very large & widening gap between questions and answers. How do we fix it?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5325/we-have-a-very-large-widening-gap-between-questions-and-answers-how-do-we-fix). As a response to that, I am trying to downvote/close some old post we probably can do better without (mainly to reduce clutter, so it becomes easier to find the good stuff). But a few are locked (by community user) for no reason I can understand. Why? Such posts cannot be downvoted or deleted.

Some examples: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15691/nonextensive-statistics  and  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49969/questions-about-seqtreedisplay-and-graphviz. (*Note that both questions have been automatically deleted in the meantime. High-rep users can still see them. No, you are not missing much.*)

Shall I just flag for unlocking?

Comment: Could you make it more specific?

Comment: Both examples you link seem to have been closed by mods. Was something changed about them after you asked?

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand why these have not long been deleted, as they should have been by point 7 of [this list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/256777). Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: @StephanKolassa Because they were locked until Scortchi unlocked them in response to this Q. Now they will be automatically deleted after some time (I think the script runs daily).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the automatic locking by the Community user is somehow to do with migrations of a question from/to this site being rejected. The rules Community follows have changed over time—see [Allow diamond moderators to reverse question migrations?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35744/225179). Anyway, please feel free to flag any such questions you think should be deleted & ask a moderator to delete them (I'm having trouble imagining situations where it'd be useful to unlock them just to allow down-voting).

Comment: Well, but is there a point in keeping the lock? I read a bit on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post  and it seems locking can also be used for "heating down" flame wars, close/unclose cycling and other unwanted activity. Years later unlocking seems natural!

Comment: @kjetilhalvorsen: If there are any you think should be merely unlocked then flag for unlocking. The examples you've given are clearly off-topic, without answers, & already closed; it seems they were locked when migration didn't work for some reason: I'm suggesting you flag them & others like them for immediate deletion, sparing yourself & others a little work, & reducing clutter more quickly.

Comment: (I've not deleted them yet, just so that other readers of this Meta post can see what we're talking about.)

Comment: I was not aware that this can happen. Here are some candidates for @kjetilbhalvorsen: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=locked%3Ayes+duplicate%3Ano+score%3A0 (search for `locked:yes duplicate:no score:0`). Note that merged questions end up locked, that's why I put `duplicate:no`. Also some threads are locked "for historical significance" (which I find a questionable practice most of the time, see https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/482), that's why I put `score:0`. One can replace it with `answers:0`.

Comment: (BTW, I noticed that some Qs are merged but *not* marked as a duplicate, e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13159/how-to-choose-a-span-parameter-with-loess. That's a bit confusing.)

Comment: NB I've already deleted several posts from @amoeba's query that kjetil flagged, & a couple more - there may not be much left to do.

Comment: @Scortchi Re merged Qs that are not marked as duplicates: do you know if it's always like that? Or does one need to tick an extra tick when merging so that the Q gets marked as a duplicate? Or did it maybe change at some moment?

Comment: @amoeba: I *think* it's always like that - the question stub is locked by merging & linked to the target, but not otherwise marked as a duplicate.