# About bibliographic entries found throughout the Q&A wiki

Tags: discussion

Are there any policies regarding bibliographic entries and/or link to online articles?
There are many references circulating along the answers provided in this Q&A website, and I think they will constitute an interesting on-line collection as the site will grow up. Having a standardized way of cross-referencing and citing would be very useful, especially if one is interested in web scraping the site or enhancing his own library of papers.

I usually display the references I found useful to support my answers following standard APA style (or something similar), but what about the many ways of citing/referencing external resources (standard http link, doi reference, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the proposed entry to the faq: [What should our FAQ contain?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-should-our-faq-contain/199#199)

Comment: My apologizes, didn't see this post... Unless relying on doi (which aren't always provided in the posts I read so far) or publisher/repository entries, it is not clear to me how one would happen to manage external links (e.g. PDFs on personal homepage, handouts, etc.) but such guidelines sound good to me.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to keep it consistent would be to build in new features in the server. Now there are tools to enter links and images. Ideally, we'd like to have links also to enter an isbn for a book or a doi for an article.