# Are probability questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

The FAQ gives:

> Statistical Analysis - Stack Exchange is for statistical analysis, data mining, machine learning, data visualization and statistical computing.

So, are questions about probability also welcome?  I have a feeling this is going to be a resounding yes, whence the next question I would ask is:

> Why is does the word "probability" not appear in the FAQ?

See also: [What's the difference between probability and statistics?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/665/whats-the-difference-between-probability-and-statistics)

Answer (score 6):

I think that probability questions should be allowed here, and that it is simply an oversight that it is not included in the FAQ.

However for more "mathematical" probability questions, the math SE may be more appropriate (in the same way that more computing questions are more appropriate for SO).

By "appropriate" I really mean that you have a better chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 3):

It depends -- a lot of probability is very mathematical, and so MathOverflow may be a more appropriate place.  You'll simply get better answers there because each community has different interests and willingness to answer varies by the type of question.  On the other hand, probability is very much central in questions regarding data and may be entirely appropriate.  You may want to consult the questions tagged probability on this site and MathOverflow to get a sense of the difference:

- [Statistical Analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability)
- [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/pr.probability)

Note that a lot of probability questions are answered here.  Maybe you can suggest appropriate wording for the FAQ:

- [What should our FAQ contain?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-should-our-faq-contain)

Then the moderators or community can decide if it works well enough to modify the FAQ.

Comment: I'd be wary of referring people to MathOverflow unless their needs are fairly high-end. [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com) may be a more suitable alternative. I'd agree that a lot of probability questions fit here, though.

Comment: Oh yeah, good point!

Answer (score 3):

Now it is in FAQ; at least we will migrate too mathematical questions.

Comment: Cool!  When I read the earlier version, I initially thought that probability was conspicuously absent.