# How to write math equations

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What typographic support is available to support display of statistical formula?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/what-typographic-support-is-available-to-support-display-of-statistical-formula)

I don't find how to write math equation. Why the functionnality of mathoverflow (latex ...) is not available?

Comment: See http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5/what-typographic-support-is-available-to-support-display-of-statistical-formula